# heroku accounts invisible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've try to use Heroku. I've a account which is name 'work'.

```
$ heroku accounts
work
```

But when I want to create a new heroku app. I faced with,

```
$ heroku create my_app
No such account: ender
```

What's that? How can I solve this problem? I can't deploy my app to heroku because of this.

Comment: You would better ask the heroku support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set your account for this project?

```
heroku accounts:set work
```

will set the account for this project and then `heroku create myapp` will use the work account for creation.